# Disable SteelBrick/CPQ Trigger from running in current trigger context

Tags: trigger, cpq, installedpackage, steelbrick, disable

I have a method that runs an update on the SBQQ Quote. If I run it on a list of Quotes the CPQ code hits a soql 101 limit exception and I have no way of fixing it. My solution would be to temporaraly disable the CPQ trigger from running in my specific trigger context and then reenable it at the end.

I found a post on the steelbrick community hoever the method is not accessible. If I go to the installed package and disable the triggers my metod works fine. I need a way of disableing the cpq triggers for my specific trigger instance while other instances will continue firing the CPQ Triggers.

[Here is a link to the post I found.](https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/Developer-Guidebook/Disabling-CPQ-Triggers-in-Apex/ta-p/15539)

I also found the VF Page "EditSettings" and Controller "SBQQ.SettingsEditorController" for the Package settings but not sure I can access it via code, and even if I could I'm assuming if I disable the trigger like that it will disable it for everyone until I re-enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CPQ triggers can be disabled in the apex context with these methods:

```
SBQQ.TriggerControl.disable();
SBQQ.TriggerControl.enable();
SBQQ.TriggerControl.isEnabled();
```

More information can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_disable_apex_triggers.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to ask Steelbrick directly by posting on their forum, but it appears that the TriggerControl methods (in the link you provided) are used to suspend or resume logic in the current transaction only. You should be able to mock this in your code in order to confirm this (do this in a Sandbox or Developer Edition).